# How to resolve multiple promises inside a multiple promise block with Q

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q

So here's the issue. For starters I have many jQuery promises (defined with `$.ajax`) and I need to act upon the values returned by parsing the data and making another block of promises.

For example my code would look like this:

```
Q.all(promisesArray).spead(function(){
 let responses = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
 .......  parse the data and get a result array which I need to use to make more promises

    What do I do here?
      Q.all(otherPromisesArray).spread(function(){....})   does not work
 });
```

Comment: If you want an array of `responses`, you should not use `spread`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here on "Chaining"

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

```
let higherScopeResult = []
Q.all(promisesArray).then(function(){
    let responses = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)[0];
    ..... do things ......
    return Q.all(otherPromisesArray).then(function(){....});
 });
```

Comment: `let higherScopeResult` - wait what?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, didn't include the rest of the related code.If you want to save the final result and process it in `done` or another `then` you need to store it outside the first promise

Comment: [No, you don't need to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572), and you almost surely should not.